# How to use Intellij Idea for a very large code base approx 5M LOC. IintelliJ automatically understands the project structure wihtout manual effort

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea, maven-3

I need a way by which the IDE should be able to understand whether the project is a maven project and build it.
without needing it to be added as a maven project as it is required in Intellij.[image]

How to make Intellij understand the maven project without any manual effort.

I need help in using Intellij Idea for a really large codebase.
The project has many modules and not all are Maven projects.
I can use eclipse to import the whole project and then eclipse is able to retain the folder structure.
But I am not able to achieve the same thing using Intellij Idea.
Is there a method to recursively check for the maven project in Intellij Idea?

And IntelliJ is not producing the correct folder structure for the maven project.
src/main/java
instead, it gives out with the pathname and repeats the path structure.

I want to move away from eclipse because it takes ages to import the project.

The project is a multimodule project. and is a combination of maven project and flat-file project.
I am importing the project as a subversion project.[image]

Comment: Please add more details to your question. No one is aware of your project structure or how you are trying to import.

Comment: We had a similar problem when we decided to turn to Intellij with our large legacy project. In the end, one person sat down and bit the bullet, and came in and *manually* defined the necessary IntelliJ config files. But then: I would rather step back and ensure that you have a good path into the future: and that is to make sure that your complete build description works out of the box with eclipse and IntelliJ. For example by making sure that all of it can be build with maven or gradle. And to then make sure *this* build config works with your IDEs.

Comment: And just saying: if possible for you, consider to use the git-svn technology. All the IDEs just work better when they can talk "git". Eclipse and large SVN was always a pain for me, and that pain completely vanished when I locally introduced git-svn for me.

Comment: Thanks for the help but the issue here is not mostly because of svn but of the project itself. 
When I am trying to build each of the module it works fine but I am not able to get a centralized view and for that  I have to rely on IDE and eclipse is not able to solve the issue quickly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The issue here looks like the structure of the project does not follow any convention (Maven) ..so IDEA IntelliJ has no kind of information how the structure should be setup... Also I would really recommend to move to Git